# Python Youtube API not returning all results (nextoken)

Tags: python, youtube-api

im trying to fetch all youtube videos with location near amsterdam airport that were made in 2012 , however im only getting 7 videos in response. I know there is way more youtube videos that were made in 2012 near this location
anybody know why im not getting all the results? Thanks!

```
# API client library
import googleapiclient.discovery
# API information
api_service_name = "youtube"
api_version = "v3"
DEVELOPER_KEY = ''
# API client
youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, developerKey = DEVELOPER_KEY)
# Notice that nextPageToken now is requested in 'fields' parameter
NewPageToken = ""
while True:
        if NewPageToken == "":
                print('request with no token')
                request = youtube.search().list(
                        part="id,snippet",
                        type='video',
                        publishedAfter='2012-01-05T11:10:04Z',
                        publishedBefore='2012-12-05T11:10:04Z',
                        location="52.3076865, 4.767424099999971",
                        locationRadius='1km',
                        maxResults=1,
                        fields="nextPageToken,items(id(videoId),snippet(publishedAt,channelId,channelTitle,title,description))"
                )
        if NewPageToken != "":
                print('request with token')
                request = youtube.search().list(
                        part="id,snippet",
                        type='video',
                        publishedAfter='2012-01-05T11:10:04Z',
                        publishedBefore='2012-12-31T11:10:04Z',
                         location="52.3076865, 4.767424099999971",
                        locationRadius='1km',
                        maxResults=1,
                        fields="nextPageToken,items(id(videoId),snippet(publishedAt,channelId,channelTitle,title,description))",
                        pageToken = NewPageToken
                )
        response = request.execute()
        
        if "nextPageToken" in response:


                print('foundToken fetching next data')
                NewPageToken = response['nextPageToken']
                
        else:
                print('noTokenFound Stopping your script')
                break
        print(response)
        # print(request)
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised that there isn't any additional results. 1 km isn't wide especially with the not very centered location that you have chosen (52.307042, 4.756420 looks more appropriate in my opinion) and don't forget that it's not YouTube that assign the location of a video, it's up to the video's creator to do so.